# Is there any git command to do update the git's indexing area on a periodic basis?

Tags: git, automation, synchronization

I am working on repo which observes frequent contribution from other guys(without being notified to other contributors), and some time I seemed to working on outdated local repo reason being I not aware of the recent updates in the remote repo.

Please suggest any solution that helps in periodic syncing (git indexing area) of the local repo with the recent changes in remote repo.

Comment: Are you looking for something that does a `git pull` automatically and periodically?  I think most devs want to perform that operation only when they explicitly decide they're ready for it.

Comment: I want to have git fetch automatically and periodically, doing pull periodically might not work as it can sometimes stuck when the branch has diverged. I am thinking of installing a cron job, please  let me know if you have any other solution

Comment: if you are not going to merge then whats the point...

Comment: no there's no builtin and a cron job would be the way to go. Definetely do a `git fetch` because it doesn't touch your working copy and thus doesn't interrupt your work.